# Fundamentals of securing a web app?

Tags: web-application, attack-prevention, single-page-app, financial

I am trying to build an app that deals with finance, specifically crypto-currency. What are the fundamentals (preferably in point form, but I'd appreciate explanations too) of securing such an app from attackers?

I am new to security and apps and I just need pointers to know what I should research on to achieve the best security on my apps. I have seen a couple of crypto-currency based apps attacked and robbed of all their funds. I am trying to avoid the same. I am using MEAN stack to develop my app. Thank you.

Comment: This is wayyy to broad.OWASP is the place to get started but i assure you it will take you a long time and even then things could go bad.

Comment: That is a field of security in itself.It's vast and cannot be answered in a Q/A as such

Comment: I understand. I am completely new to this field, so I just pointers on where to start. Thanks for pointing me to OWASP. I have another question though. I know many sites up and running that I am sure the developers only if they had no security expat working on them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96721/discussion-between-yulepale-and-vipul-nair).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically OWASP created a series to help developers in creating secure web apps without going in too deep into it.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/tree/master/cheatsheets) for that. If you read, understand, and follow it carefully, this should be enough.